# Push a panel out of browser view on resizing or on a particular resolution

Tags: html, css

[image]

Here, on smaller resolutions when panel-B or Panel-A is toggled(show/hide) then it is not pushing Panel-A off screen *without horizontal scroll*.

Similarly, either Panel-C or Panel-B is visible at a time.

Similarly, Panel-C is not pushing Panel-A to the right when small resolutions.

How to push div in between Panel-B outside a screen(only that part that is required) when corresponding Panel-A or Panel-B is toggled on smaller resolutions so that Panel-C or Panel-B can take its min-width and properly visible.

When panel-c or panel-b is visible(either one of them should be visible at a time), then panel-A should push to left of the screen or right screen respectively when the resolution is low:

```
 Panel-C            Panel- A              Panel-B
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;width:100%;">
  <div style="display:flex;width:100%;justify-content:center;">
    <div style="min-width:300px;max-width:500px;margin-right:30px;display:none;">
      Panel C
    </div>
    <div style="min-width:520px;max-width:668px;">
      Panel A
    </div>
    <div style="min-width:300px;max-width:500px;margin-left:30px;display:block;">
      Panel B
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add the full html? I don't see the mentioned panel-C on your code

Comment: Updated code. Please let me know if anything missing.

Comment: I've read the question a few times and I cannot draw a picture in my head of what are your intentions. Maybe you could do a simple draw/representation of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @a--m , added image for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I found the question particularly confusing, but reading from the title I think what you are looking for is a solution to change elements style based on the viewport size (resolution). This can be achieved by using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Here is an example, based on your code but with CSS extracted to its own file and simplified to keep it short:

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pan {
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
}

@media (max-width: 300px) {
  .pan__b {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .pan__c {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="group">
    <div class="pan pan__a">
      Panel A
    </div>
    <div class="pan pan__b">
      Panel B
    </div>
    <div class="pan pan__c">
      Panel C
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if this is what you intend, or if I understood it wrong.

Comment: Sorry, You misunderstood the question. When panel-c or panel-b is visible(either one of them should be visible at a time), then panel-A should push to left of screen or right screen respectively when resolution is low ie required.